# Can't update react state in context hook

Tags: cookies, react-hooks, local-storage, next.js13

Lately I have been working on a next.js project using latest `next 13.8`. But while using the context hook I got into a trouble.

## Context

```js
"use client";
// REACT ESSENTIALS
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
// IMPORTING CONTEXT
import AuthContext from "./context";

// OTHER IMPORTS
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { v4 } from "uuid";

export const AuthState = (props) => {
  // VARIABLE SETTINGS
  const host = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKENED_API_URI;
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  // FUNCTION TO SAVE DATA TO BOTH LOCALSTORAGE & COOKIE
  const createCookiesToLocalStorage = (name, val) => {
    Cookies.set(name, val);
    localStorage.setItem(name, val);
  };

  // INITIATING USER TO GET JWT
  const initiateUser = async (credentials) => {
    const { identifier, password } = credentials;
    const req = await fetch(host + "/api/auth/local", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ identifier, password }),
    });

    const response = await req.json();

    if (response.jwt) {
      setUser(response.user);

      createCookiesToLocalStorage("jwt", response.jwt);
      createCookiesToLocalStorage("user", JSON.stringify(response.user));
    }
    return response;
  };

  // GETTING USER AGAIN WITH THE JWT
  const getSetUser = async (jwt) => {
    const extUsr = Cookies.get("user") || localStorage.getItem("user");
    if (extUsr) {
      console.log(extUsr);
      setUser(extUsr);
    } else {
      const req = await fetch(
        host + "/api/users/me?populate=*&populate=profile.image",
        {
          method: "GET",
          mode: "cors",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
              "Accept, Authorization, Content-Type",
            Accept: "*/*",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
          },
        }
      );
      const response = await req.json();
      setUser(response);
    }
  };

  // Other stuffs 

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
        initiateUser,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuthContext = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

So whenever I run `initiateUser()` command it stores the "user" object as a json array to `localStorage` (also in cookies using `js-cookie`). But whenever I try to assign that json arrray to the user state it is returning null.

Simply the `setUser()` command is not assigning the "user" array fetched from `localStorgae`.
The console.log(extUsr) ouput isn't null, rather it is returnibg the user array.

I want somebody to help me out with how to set that fetched details to that react state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually after browsing through my code deeply I got to know I was saving the code as string format not as an object. That's why I was getting weird type of responses.

So I did the following changes

```js
 // INITIATING USER TO GET JWT
  const initiateUser = async (credentials) => {
    const { identifier, password } = credentials;
    const req = await fetch(host + "/api/auth/local", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ identifier, password }),
    });

    const response = await req.json();

    if (response.jwt) {
      setUser(response.user);

      createCookiesToLocalStorage("jwt", response.jwt);
      createCookiesToLocalStorage("user", JSON.stringify(response.user));
    }
    return response;
  };

  // UPDATE USER WITH JWT
  const fetchToSetUser = async (jwt) => {
    const req = await fetch(
      host + "/api/users/me?populate=*&populate=profile.image",
      {
        method: "GET",
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Accept, Authorization, Content-Type",
          Accept: "*/*",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
        },
      }
    );
    const response = await req.json();
    setUser(response);
  };

  // GETTING USER AGAIN WITH THE JWT
  const getSetUser = async (jwt, _usr) => {
    if (_usr) {
      setUser(JSON.parse(_usr));
    } else {
      await fetchToSetUser(jwt);
    }
  };
```